# C++ console game input && refresh function

Tags: c++, input, game-engine

I am writing a small console adventure game and I faced a few problems.
1. The input is kinda laggy, I'm using while loop ( while(getch() == 'w') ). After a key is pressed the first time, nothing happens (you have to press it 2 times) and if you switch directions (press key A/D/S) it also doesn't react the 1st time. If you hold a key, it works fine. How can this be fixed?

2. Here's the function I use to refresh game (render the game scene when a key is pressed):

```
    void refresh(char map[Y][X])
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i<UP; i++)
    {
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<Y; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k<LEFT; k++)
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for (int j = 0; j<X; j++)
        {
            cout<<map[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

When I use this function once, it's ok, but when they key is pressed or held multiple times - the game field starts to flash. I figured that I need to redraw only a part of the field (where changes are made/movements are done), not the whole field. Can you offer any ideas how to do that?

The sample code for input:

```
while(getch() == 'w')
    {
        if (map[y-1][x]!= WALL)
        {
        map[y-1][x] = CHARACTER;
        map [y][x] = ' ';
        y--;
        refresh(map);
        Sleep(SPEED); // this is unnecessary, SPEED is 0, I just kept it for tests
        }
    }
```

Basically, the main function looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    (...) Variables (...)
    generateMap(FROM FILE);
    refresh(); // First initialization of the field
    while (getch() != 'q') // While not quitting
    {
    while(getch() == 'w')
    {
        if (THE FIELD ABOVE IS NOT OCCUPIED)
        {
             setSomeVariables();
             refresh(THE GAMEFIELD);
        }
    }
    }
    while(getch() == 's')
    {
        if (THE FIELD BELOW IS NOT OCCUPIED)
        {
             setSomeVariables();
             refresh(THE GAMEFIELD);
        }
    }
    }
    while(getch() == 'a')
    {
        if (THE FIELD ON THE LEFT IS NOT OCCUPIED)
        {
             setSomeVariables();
             refresh(THE GAMEFIELD);
        }
    }
    }
    while(getch() == 'd')
    {
        if (THE FIELD ON THE RIGHT IS NOT OCCUPIED)
        {
             setSomeVariables();
             refresh(THE GAMEFIELD);
        }
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the value returned by `getch()` the first time?

Comment: On the first time it doesn't return anything (the loop doesn't run), I've added the code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `system("cls")`, it is really slow, instead set the cursor on the beginning of the screen with the following code:

```
COORD cur = {0, 0};
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cur);
```

You should call `getch()` only one time in the loop, like this:

```
char key;

do
{
    key = getch();

    if(key == 'w')
    {
        //do something
    }

    //the other if statements

}while(key != 'q');
```

Comment: What library do those functions come from?

Comment: you have to include windows.h

Answer (score 2):

1. The code should have only one getch() in the whole code (if possible) and inside a switch you do the action for each input. So, it is switch inside the loop, and not loops inside the switch. Something like this:

   while ((ch = getch()) != 'q')
   {
     switch (ch)
     {
     case 'a':
       GoLeft();
       break;
     ...
     }
   }
2. There is a library called [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) that you can use to move the cursor around the screen, and write anything anywhere.

Comment: 1. I've added the code now.



2. Thank you, I'll use ncurses if there's no other alternatives, but I'd like to stick to the default libraries.

Comment: There is no default library for display drawing, as there might not be a display at all in some hardware. And I think this is not the whole relevant code. Do you have more than one getch in the code?

Comment: Yup, I have 5 of them (W,A,S,D for controls and Q for quit).
Should I paste the whole code? Most of the variables aren't in english, so it might be complicated to understand some of them.

Comment: In the code you posted there is a "master getch" while loop that checks if the input key is 'q'. This getch is "eating up" your first key. Change the code according to my edited answer. Unfortunately code formatting stopped working, but the code is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is calling getch() multiple times.  Have only one loop, and call getch() once per loop, and store the result.  Test that result for each value (q, w, s, ...) for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thank you! Your and flagbug's solutions worked, I'd accept both answers if it was possible.

Comment: I can't - it requires 15 reputation :/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use function input() as it stands:

```
void input()
{   if (GetKeyState('W') & 0x8000)    // That means when button "W" is pressed
       ... your code ... 
     // (changes global variables, or you can pass variables by reference)
}
```

without any getch() command that stops your game every single time.

---

You can use it with the draw() and calculate()/refresh() functions in the main(), like:

```
int main()
{
   ... other part of code ...

   while (!gameover)
   {
      input();
      calculate();
      draw();
   }
}
```

so that you will always have some sort of input value before the calculations, and then you would draw (+ it's much easier to debug ;) )